# Connect to Hyper-V 2008 R2 using libvirt

Tags: hyper-v, libvirt

I'm trying to connect to a Hyper-V 2008 R2 server using gem ruby-libvirt. I keep getting the following error : `Call to virConnectOpenAuth failed: internal error: Transport error during enumeration: Could not connect (7) (Libvirt::ConnectionError)`.

However, connection to a Hyper-V 2012 server, using the same code, works.

Have I made a mistake ?
Here is the code I'm using (following libvirt documentation http://libvirt.org/ruby/examples/open_auth.rb)

```
conn = Libvirt::open_auth('hyperv://my_server/?transport=http',
                      [Libvirt::CRED_AUTHNAME, Libvirt::CRED_PASSPHRASE],
                      "") do |cred|
    if cred["type"] == Libvirt::CRED_AUTHNAME
        res = "username"
    elsif cred["type"] == Libvirt::CRED_PASSPHRASE
        res = "passwd"
    else
        raise "Unsupported credential #{cred['type']}"
    end
    res
end
```

In top of that, libvirt doc says it supports Hyper-V 2008 R2 (http://libvirt.org/drvhyperv.html) but here (https: //www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2014-April/msg00802.html) is said it might not be anymore due to Hyper-V 2012. Would this be the issue ?

I'm using ruby-libvirt 0.5.2 and libvirt 1.2.2.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Not clear the actual scenario

Comment: Could you tell me what is not clear with my scenario ?

With the same code (as displayed above), I can connect to Hyper-V 2012 but no into Hyper-V 2008 R2. I want to know if my code needs to be corrected for Hyper-V 2008 or if libvirt doesn't support anymore Hyper-V 2008 R2 (as discussed in https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2014-April/msg00802.html).